# Celery keep firing task every 5 minutes if I use crontab

Tags: python, django, celery

Celery keep firing task every 5 minutes if I use crontab.

I have django project with requirements:

```
Python3.4
celery==3.1.17
Django==1.8
```

And I have follow options in settings.py

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-day': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.every_day',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour=0),
    },
}
```

Celery works under supervisord:

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --concurrency=2 -Ofair
celery beat -A proj  -l info
```

After 00:30 at midnight Celery sends task first time and then keep firing it until 03:30.

I found issue on github with similar symptoms, but it didn't help.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? according to your crontab, your task should fire at 00:30, 01:30 and so on until 23:30. what in fact does happen?

Comment: according to crontab (30 0 * * *) it should fire only once at 00:30 at midnight

Comment: you are right, sorry, somehow missed the hour=0 parameter

Comment: it's ok, what realy bother me it's why crontab from Celery works such way

Comment: I can only share with you my personal experience - I had very similar problems with Celery's crontab in 2011, and couldn't resolve them no matter what I tried. Had to just stop using it and switch back to the good old cron.

Comment: I already did that, but it means small part of project cannot be updated simultaneously with all code base during deploy.